# Einstein Activity Capture: Emails are not shared on records

Tags: einstein

I've got an issue with Einstein Activity Capture. All emails captured from collaborators who have standard permissions (meaning not the "view all data" privilege) aren't shared by default - despite the fact that in Setup, default sharing is turned on (in the Einstein Activity Capture) tab, and in their private email settings, sharing is turned on as well.

Am I missing something in the permission set possibly? Where would I start looking?

Thanks & much love from Germany,
Dominik

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Note that Einstein Activity Capture saves all the records in servers outside of Salesforce - meaning it's not a normal Task activity record that you're used to, and may play by different rules when it comes to sharing.

Comment: @BrianMiller you mentioned "Einstein Activity Capture saves all the records in servers outside of Salesforce" ... how do we know this? Is this documented?

Comment: I think this is [the official source](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.inbox_considerations.htm&type=5) and the [EAC Security Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sales_activity_capture_security.pdf) page 7 shows a diagram about it.  Google around and you'll see articles a plenty about it

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found the answer: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pokrQAA

Each user needs to switch their private Einstein Activity Capture settings to "Only Me" and then back to "Share with Everyone". Seems to be a glitch.